# Trouble in understading behaviour of std::transform

Tags: c++, std

Consider this -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

int main()
{
  typedef std::list<int> L;
  L l(5);
  typedef L::const_iterator CI;
  typedef L::iterator I;
  CI cb = l.begin(), ce = l.end();
  I b = l.begin();
  std::transform(cb, --ce, ++b, std::bind2nd(std::plus<CI::value_type>(), 1));
  std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<CI::value_type>(std::cout\
));
  std::cout<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Acccording to me its output should be 01111 as transform will iterate from first to "second last" element of list add 1 to each element and overwrite from "2nd" to "last" element.

But to my surprise output is 01234

What am I missing ? I read the documentation of transform on cppreference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your are storing the result of each individual transformation into the next element of the **source** container, so the next input of the transform function will be the output of the previous transform (because of how you defined the input and output ranges).

In other words, the `transform()` algorithm will process the first element of your container (`0`), add `1` to it, and store the result (`1`) as the second element *of that same container*. Then, it will process the second element, which is now `1`; it will add `1` to it, and store the result (`2`) as the third element of the container. And so on until you get to the last iteration.

If you want to get the output `01111`, you should either store the result of the transform into a *diffferent* container ([**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=29ef31a90aaaaa2a3b37dadce282db65-a63ad9fea3739cb794a74965e5d28fb3)):

```
std::vector<int> out(l.size());
std::transform(cb, --ce, ++out.begin(), 
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    std::bind2nd(std::plus<CI::value_type>(), 1));
```

Or use a different iteration strategy, [as suggested by DyP in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321637/trouble-in-understading-behaviour-of-stdtransform/17321784#comment25124665_17321784) ([**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ecea30a244470df1a5c14173b7c2bbb4-a63ad9fea3739cb794a74965e5d28fb3)):

```
 std::transform(++cb, ce, ++b, std::bind2nd(std::plus<CI::value_type>(), 1));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to iterate from ++cb to ce, output at ++b? Like `transform(++cb, ce, ++b, ...)`

Comment: @Andy: thanks for clarifying, I actually thought transform starts writing after performing operation on whole range but i was wrong

Answer (score 3):

Since you are starting to add elements into the same container at `++b`, there is an off by one offset, which means that you insert element `i` plus `1` into position `i+1`. So you are accummulating the sum as you move along. Assuming transform processes the elements sequentially, this is what the first three iterations will do:

> 0 0 0 0 0

Add 1 to position 0, put it in position 1

> 0 1 0 0 0

Add 1 to position 1, put it in position 2

> 0 1 2 0 0

Add 1 to position 2, put it in position 3

> 0 1 2 3 0